# WordPress files permissions on Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, file-permissions, file-ownership

What is the best approach with files permissions for WordPress site on Apache? I'd like to be able to upload plugins directly to my local server. I'm able to do that if I change ownership on my WordPress instance files to `_www`. On the other hand, this makes OS X asking for password each time I'm saving any of those files. I want to save them without typing password.

What can I do to satisfy both needs?

Comment: create a group, put yourself and apache into that group, then chown all of the files to that group, and grant the group the proper permissions.

Comment: I am currently in `staff` group. `_www` is also a group and it's used by Apache. Can I belong to more than one group at once?

Comment: yes, you can be in as many groups as you want. otherwise that'd defeat the purpose of having groups.

Comment: How can I do it? On my user edition screen I see text input to provide my group. Plus, I don't see any groups on the list, even though GUI allows to add groups.

Comment: /etc/group? not sure where osx keeps unix-level group details.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:
make sure the user is all over wordpress files as owner ang group.
The commands are:

`chown user:user  -R *`

Then permissions are these:

`sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +`

`sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +`

`sudo chmod 660 wp-config.php`

You can also add these permissions to uploads folder:

`chmod 755 -R uploads`

And you should be ready to go.